# Using JQuery autocomplete with list of objects yields no search results

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autocomplete

In my controller, I get a list of brands:

```
        private IEnumerable<Brand> GetBrands()
    {
        List<Brand> brandList = new List<Brand>();

        List<Brand> brands = Brand.GetList();
        brands = brands.OrderBy(b => b.BrandCode).ToList();

        return brands;
    }
```

I then stuff that list in a ViewBag for my Edit view:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
         this.ViewBag.BrandList = this.GetBrands();
        }
```

And in my Edit view, I'm trying to implement autocomplete:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var brandList = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.ViewBag.BrandList));
        $('#BrandCode').autocomplete({
            source: brandList,
            minLength: 3
        });

        console.log(brandList);
    });
</script>
```

From the console logging, I see the brandList is a list of Objects:

[image: console log]

But I can't get a match in the BrandCode field?  What am I doing wrong?

[image: autocomplete]

**EDIT**:
Here is the Brand entity:

```
public class Brand : PersistantEntity
{
    private IBrandRepository repository;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this.repository.Id; }
        set { this.repository.Id = value; }
    }

    public string BrandCode
    {
        get { return this.repository.BrandCode; }
        set { this.repository.BrandCode = value; }
    }

    protected override Repository.Abstract.IRepository Repository
    {
        get { return this.repository; }
        set { this.repository = value as IBrandRepository; }
    }

    public Brand()
    {
        this.repository = RepositoryFactory.CreateFromConfig<IBrandRepository>();
    }

    internal Brand(IBrandRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

}
```

Comment: The autocomplete is looking for the data in a Brand object. You might want to try the autocomplete on a Property in the object or something similar. Can you post your Brand Object?

Comment: @lopezbertoni - i edited my question and added the Brand entity

Comment: Instead of passing a list of entities/objects to the autocomplete try passing a list of properties. For instance what's in Brand.BrandCode

Comment: OK.  I changed the definition of GetBrands to be a list of BrandCode, and it's working now.  I will post the new definition.  thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the definition of GetBrands to return a list of strings (BrandCodes) instead of Brand objects.  This fixed the problem.  Here's the new definition:

```
        private IEnumerable<string> GetBrands()
    {
        List<string> brandList = new List<string>();

        List<Brand> brands = Brand.GetList();
        brands = brands.OrderBy(b => b.BrandCode).ToList();

        foreach (var brand in brands)
        {
            brandList.Add(brand.BrandCode.ToString()); 
        }

        return brandList;
    }
```